# Counting sort algorithm doesn't work in C

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, counting

My task is to make a counting sort algorithm in C. The compiler doesn't make any reasons to not make a program, but it doesn't work. While debugging debugger shows the second `for` contain as an error so I am asking where is an error because I can't see it.

```
const int k = 77; 
const int n = 1000;

int T[n]; 
int Tp[n]; 
int TPom[k]; 

int i; 

  for(i = 0 ; i < k ; i++)
    TPom[i] = 0;                

  for(i = 0 ; i < k ; i++)
    TPom[T[i]]= TPom[T[i]]+1;               

  for(i = 1 ; i < k ; ++i)
    TPom[i] += TPom[i-1];       

  for(i = n-1 ; i >= 0 ; --i)
     Tp[--TPom[T[i]]] = T[i];
```

Comment: If you're wondering why people are down-voting your answer, it's because: __1.__ Don't just say _"It's not working!"_. Provide the exact output you saw and what you expected to see. __2.__ You did not provide a [short, self-contained, correct, compilable example](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2):

There are a few problems, so I'll give you some hints:

- The second loop is wrong. Hint: how many elements does `T` contain?
- The third loop is not wrong, but is unnecessary. I personally find it easier to think about the algorithm *without* this loop (you might disagree).
- The final loop is wrong. You want to iterate over the values `0` through `k-1`, populating `Tp`. The loop shouldn't even reference `T`.

Comment: Could you write it down please because I don't get it.

Comment: @user2271281: I am sorry, but if I were to just give you the solution, you wouldn't learn anything. But don't despair: you're *almost* there; the remaining bugs are easy to fix.

Comment: for(i = 0 ; i < k ; i++)
    TPom[i] = 0;                
 
  for(j = 1 ; i < k ; i++)
    TPom[T[i]]= TPom[T[i]]+1;               
                                
  for(i = 1 ; i <= k ; i++)
    TPom[i] = TPom[i]+TPom[i-1];       
                                
  for(j = n ; j >= 1 ; j--)
  {
  
     Tp[TPom[T[j]]]=T[j];
  TPom[T[j]]= TPom[T[j]]-1;

Comment: I have changed it but now debugger is stopping at 4th loop.